# An error appears if Selenium Webdriver test that is run by TeamCity clicks on Browse button for uploading a file

Tags: c#, browser, webdriver, nunit, teamcity

I run Selenium Webdriver tests by TeamCity on local server (Windows Server 2008). Also I use test automation framework for working with browser's dialog when I try to upload or download file. When I run the test on my local computer using NUnit, everything is OK. The test where the problem appears:

1. click on Browse button
2. type the path to the file that should be uploaded in Browser's dialog
3. click on Open button

When I run this test by TeamCity, an error appears after clicking on Browse button:
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop refers to a location that is unavailable. It could be on a hard drive on this computer, or a network. Check to make sure that the disk is properly inserted, or that you are connected to the Internet or your nerwork, and then try again. If it still cannot be located, the information might have been moved to a different location".
As I understand, the browser try to open default folder where uploaded files should be located. If I run the test by NUnit from my mashine this folder is located in My Documents. When the test is run by Teamcity, owner of the browser's process is SYSTEM. So, browser cannot find correct location when uploaded files should be located.
I tried to change default folder of SYSTEM using regedit, but the error still appears. Please, help me to solve this problem, guys.

Comment: Have you tried running teamcity agent under another account?

Comment: Sure. Also I tried to run it on another server. An error appears in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise against such a combined approach. If you want to test the file transfer stuff you should not try to go via the file chooser of the browser, because they break out of the webdriver universe. Instead i would recommend setting the default download path as property in the webdriver configuration. Something like this should do:

```
profile.SetPreference(“browser.download.folderList”, 1);
profile.SetPreference(“browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting”, false);
profile.SetPreference(“browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk”, “application/xml”);
```

a [good article about the subject](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/) suggest that you even don't need that, but test the download stuff with a nicer solution called [Powder-Monkey](https://github.com/Ardesco/Powder-Monkey).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I thought about something like this. But I'm wonder to know, why this error appears if my solution is used and what the way to solve this problem is.